# Read Gedcom file and store in Database

Tags: asp.net, file, gedcom

I want to read a Gedcom file and store in sql server .
GEDCOM is a file format which allows genealogy files to be shared between different genealogy software applications. GEDCOM stands for GEnealogical Data COMmunications.

Can any one help me on this issue ???

Comment: Do you want to store the text of the file into the server, or do you want to convert the GEDCOM format into a data-structure you have defined? Will the user be uploading the file, or is it already on the server? What have you tried so far?

Comment: User will upload any gedcom file in my web page and i want to store that file in my database as according to that information i want to create a Family timeline .

Comment: You'll want a GEDCOM parser then (http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gedcom+parser). Which specific areas are you having problems with though?

Comment: I successfully read the gedcom file and converted that file into xml file. Now how can i maintain the relationship available in gedcom file and store that information in database

Comment: You'll need to define an appropriate database structure. Without knowing your requirements, it's not obvious what that should be, but if you've managed to convert a GEDCOM file into an XML file (which is not easy in itself!) then your XML structure should be similar to the database structure you will need.

Comment: See i have a request . The request is for a “Build Your Family Timeline”.  The users should be able to import a Gedcom file or enter basic info (date of birth and place of birth) then we will show their history on a google map along with Events that have happened near where they lived or Events that happened during their lives. User can see this timeline at any time . so for this what i am planning .... if user uploads any gedcom file then i will store that file in my database and according to the information available in that file i will create a google map.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way I've found to query GEDCOM data in SQLServer is to use the import / export features that come with [The Master Genealogist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_Genealogist) application.  The Master Genealogist lets you export data to csv.  Once you have the data in csv you can then use the Data Transformation Services wizards of SQLServer to import it.

I've certainly had success exporting data from The Master Genealogist into SQLServer but have not as yet tested the GEDCOM import feature.

Otherwise, you could always checkout the GenealogyJ codebase and take a look at the [GEDCOM reader](https://genj.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/genj/trunk/genj/src/core/genj/io/GedcomReaderFactory.java) there.  If java is not to your liking try the perl Gedcom module instead.

Answer (score 0):

first, convert gedcom in Gedcom XML
after
http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc188730%28en-us%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[**Oxy-Gen**](http://www.oxy-gen-soft.net/index_en.php) is a tool that allows you to convert to the following formats :

- HTML (Browser display)
- CSV (Excel, Open Office, ...)
- SQL (Oracle)
- MySQL (PHP)
- XML (machine 2 machine)

If you don't need automatic import/export features, this tool should suit your needs.

If you do need automatic import/export features, you might want to look for a GEDCOM parsing library in the programming language of your choice.